# failed to run expo run:android

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, expo

I got this error when trying to run `expo run:android` and can't find any solution for it.

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/amin/Projects/profishop/taksabad/android/app/src/main/java/com/mapsabad/profishop/generated/BasePackageList.java:1: error: illegal '.'
package com.mapsabad.profishop..generated;
                               ^
/Users/amin/Projects/profishop/taksabad/android/app/src/main/java/com/mapsabad/profishop/MainApplication.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
package com.mapsabad.profishop.;
                               ^
/Users/amin/Projects/profishop/taksabad/android/app/src/main/java/com/mapsabad/profishop/MainApplication.java:14: error: illegal '.'
import com.mapsabad.profishop..generated.BasePackageList;
                              ^
/Users/amin/Projects/profishop/taksabad/android/app/src/main/java/com/mapsabad/profishop/MainActivity.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
package com.mapsabad.profishop.;
                               ^
/Users/amin/Projects/profishop/taksabad/android/app/src/debug/java/com/mapsabad/profishop/ReactNativeFlipper.java:7: error: <identifier> expected
package com.mapsabad.profishop.;
                               ^
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 19s
519 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 516 up-to-date
/Users/amin/Projects/profishop/taksabad/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /Users/amin/Projects/profishop/taksabad/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:472:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at spawnGradleAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/spawnGradleAsync.ts:44:18)
    at actionAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/runAndroid.ts:110:9)
```

I also tried expo eject and then run `npx react-native run-android` bug I got same error again.

react native version : 0.63.4

Anyone have an idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Where does the text `com.mapsabad.profishop.` come from? It's a value you specified. It obviously should not have a `.` at the end, so find where you specified the value, and remove the `.`, then ask yourself why you put a period there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing period from `com.mapsabad.profishop.` as the logs indicate this as an error in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had the word "native" in the package name in ReactNativeFlipper. Think it got copied from the name field in my app.json Expo file. The word "native" was even marked in red text when I opened the file so I solved it by renaming it.